# How do I import saltstack into Python?

Tags: salt-stack

How do I import saltstack into Python, i.e. import salt?  I want to use anaconda (or any technique that works).

I am using python 3.4 and salt 2017.7.4.  I can see the python modules here:

/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/modules

but when using Python 3.4 I cannot do conda install salt (or pip install salt).

Comment: Saltstack is not a Python package. [Installation instructions](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/installation/index.html) are here, then use `import salt.client`, `import salt.config`, `import salt.loader`, etc.

Comment: It's already installed . salt --version
salt 2017.7.4 (Nitrogen).  I used install_salt.sh.

Comment: Then no need to install via pip or conda, unless you mean a client like https://github.com/ojarva/salt-client-python?

Comment: no.  I mean to use the salt API that is already there.  The "import salt" cannot find it.  I am now downgrading to Python 2.7 since those instructions you showed me says Salt does not support Python > 3 (contradicting its own release notes.).

Comment: Josh see below.  That worked. But I thought conda would look on the system path for packages it cannot find in the created environment.  Aparently not in this case. So it sort of remains an open question even though what I wrote below worked.

Answer (score 0):

When using Anaconda it appears that Python does not look for salt in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt.

And when you search for it with conda it is not there.

```
conda search salt
Loading channels: done

PackagesNotFoundError:  

  - salt
```

So I install it with pip:

```
pip install salt
```

And now the import works.

Maybe this means someone needs to update the conda repository?  And it also raises the question of when to use conda install versus pip install.

Comment: did you try [`conda install -c conda-forge salt`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/salt)?

Comment: OK.  That works too.  Want to look at this error?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52095272/ssl-error-on-8-on-saltstack-using-tornado