# SSL Error on 8 on SaltStack using Tornado

Tags: ssl, curl, salt-stack

If I run:

> curl -si localhost:8000/login -H "Accept: application/json" -d
>   username='salt' -d password='salt' -d eauth='pam'

It gives this error:

> Process Manager starting! Enter PEM pass phrase: [WARNING ] SSL Error
>   on 8 ('127.0.0.1', 50408): [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:1407609C:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:http request [ERROR   ] Uncaught
>   exception Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line
>   693, in _server_request_loop
>       ret = yield conn.read_response(request_delegate)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 870, in run
>       value = future.result()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 215, in
>   result
>       raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 876, in run
>       yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line
>   168, in _read_message
>       quiet_exceptions=iostream.StreamClosedError)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 870, in run
>       value = future.result()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 215, in
>   result
>       raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)   File "", line 3, in raise_exc_info SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:1407609C:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:http request

Here is:

> tail /etc/salt/master
>       # socket backlog
>       backlog: 128
>       ssl_crt: /etc/pki/api/certs/cert.pem
>       # no need to specify ssl_key if cert and key
>       # are in one single file
>       ssl_key: /etc/pki/api/certs/key.pem
>       debug: False
>       disable_ssl: False
>       webhook_disable_auth: False
>       cors_origin: null

And I copied my self-signed certs to the location shown above and added it to the root CA:

> sudo cp cert.pem /usr/share/ca-certificates/ sudo dpkg-reconfigure
>   ca-certificates

Answer (score 0):

It appears you cannot use a virtual environment with the salt-api.  I removed Anaconda and upgrade to Python 3 and now it works, yet it gives a warning, but it gives no error:

> curl -si localhost:8000/login >     -H "Accept: application/json" >
>   -d username='salt' >     -d password='salt' >     -d eauth='pam'

Does not throw an error, only a warning:

> [DEBUG   ] Process Manager starting! [WARNING ] SSL Error on 11
>   ('127.0.0.1', 46632): [SSL: HTTP_REQUEST] http request (_ssl.c:600)